# How can I achieve this “nebula” effect?

Tags: materials

[image]

Hello! I wonder if someone could help me to achieve this kind of “nebula blurry” effect. I ve been watching a lot of nebula tutorials but the result is too cloudy. Thanks!

Comment: could you precise what it means? Playing with Depth of Field doesn't give what you want?

Comment: Yeah, I tried too but it was not even close. I tried with subsurface scattering touching the options and I made something TOO blurry. That image has like parts of the same object with definition and some parts are completely blurry.

Comment: I don't think this could be achieved without either particles or a smoke/volumetric simulation. Thing is it would probably require an impractically high amount of particles or a very detailed simulation with lots of vortex and force fields I'm not sure Blender would be able to cope with